# stagger loading of ajax responses

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page that displays the status of all objects in a given set of database schemas. Schema objects are shown as a hierarchical tree (schema > object type > object name). There are a lot (thousands) of objects. The status is source-control related (is the object modified/deleted/added/unchanged in comparison to the source controlled version?).

I use a bit of ajax to load an icon representing the status of each object with the intention being that the status can be displayed whenever the asynchronous check completes. What actually happens, is that the loading icons freeze and after all statii requests have resolved, all icons display at the same time. This is unintended and gives the page load an undesirable and distinctly synchronous feel. I envisaged the loading icons changing individually to the correct status icon in some sort of staggered order.

How can I modify my javascript to give a better experience (icons transforming from loading gif to status png individually, rather than all at the same time)?

Here's some code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
@foreach (var schema in Model) {
    foreach (var o in schema.Objects) {
        @:$.getJSON('@Url.Action("ObjectStatus")', {service:'@schema.Service', schema:'@schema.Name', objectName:'@o.Name', objectType:'@o.Type'}, function (data) {
            @:$('#@string.Format("{0}-{1}", schema.Name, o.Name)').attr('src', '/Content/images/' + data + '.png');
        @:});
    }
}
});
```

...

```
<ul id="treeview">
@foreach (var schema in Model)
{
    <li>@schema.Name<br />
        <ul>
        @foreach (var t in schema.Objects.Select(x=>x.Type).Distinct())
        {
            var objectType = t;
            <li>@string.Format("{0}{1}", objectType, objectType.EndsWith("x") ? "es" : "s")<br />   
                <ul>
                @foreach (var o in schema.Objects.Where(x => x.Type == objectType))
                {
                    <li>
                        <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/loading.gif")" alt="checking status..." id="@string.Format("{0}-{1}", schema.Name, o.Name)"/>
                        @Html.ActionLink(o.Name, "Diff", "Browse", new { service = schema.Service, schema = schema.Name, objectName = o.Name, objectType }, null)
                    </li>
                }
                </ul>
            </li>
        }
        </ul>
    </li>
}
</ul>
```

and here's what the finished tree looks like:

[image: tree view]

Comment: Are you wanting the updates to happen in order or in whatever order they happen to return by?

Comment: not fussed about the order, just want them to load individually rather than all at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to get a true 'multi threaded' look and feel with javascript; it's simply not  available.

What you can do is push all of your requests into an array, and then `shift` the first element off of the list for your next ajax request.

```
function getResponse()
{
    if(myRequestArray.length == 0)
       return;

    var elementToRequest = myRequestArray.shift();

    $.ajax({
       url: '/some/url/',
       data: { someData: elementToRequest.someData },
       success: getResponse
    });
}
```

Your callback will be the method invoked so you start the next request. This way, your UI can remain 'responsive' while the ajax requests complete. It's going to appear synchronous only so far as the ordering of the elements in the array get updated in order.

Comment: Your success callback will need additional code (including the call again) to update the images, but you get the idea =D

Answer (score 0):

May not be best solution out there, but try this..

set

```
async : false
```

on your jquery call..